# Using feof to read until end of file

Tags: c

So I have read multiple posts on why `feof` doesn't work properly and they all utilize using a `while(fscanf(...) == 1)` to read to end of file, the problem I have is that I have temp values that are different for each loop, because it is reading each line processing it and then moving to next line. The code I currently have reads all the input properly but prints the last line twice. I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this instead of just doing a hack job and removing the last line processed, since it is processed twice.

```
void readInputFile(Customer customers[]) {
    FILE *input = fopen("hw4input.txt", "r");

    while (!feof(input)) {
        char tempName[MAXNAMELEN];
        int tempQuantity;
        char tempItem[MAXNAMELEN];
        double tempPrice;
        fscanf(input, "%s %d %s $%lf", &tempName, &tempQuantity, &tempItem, &tempPrice);
        printf("%s %d %s %.2lf\n", tempName, tempQuantity, tempItem, tempPrice);
    }
    printf("EOF\n");
    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `if(fscanf(input,...) == 4) printf(...) else break;`

Comment: Besides the ***essential*** check of the return value fron `scanf` family you have passed incorrect arguments: remove the `&` where you are passing to `%s` format spec. `if(fscanf(input, "%s %d %s $%lf", tempName, &tempQuantity, tempItem, &tempPrice) != 4) . . .;` Moreover you make no attempt to prevent string overflow, by restricting string input lengths.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not worried about string overflow, because this is a homework assignment and the input file isonly going to be in one format and nothign else.

Comment: @Jacob start as you mean to continue: write robust code from day 1. Cardinal sin: assuming input data is as you expect it to be. It won't be, even if you prepared it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `feof()` to detect end of file before attempting to read from the file. `feof()` will return the state of the end-of-file status only after a failed attempt at reading data from the file.

You should instead read values from the stream, with `fscanf()` for a quick and dirty throw away toy program, or with `fgets()` for a more robust parser:

```
void readInputFile(Customer customers[]) {
    FILE *input = fopen("hw4input.txt", "r");

    if (input != NULL) {
        char name[1024];
        int quantity;
        char item[1024];
        double price;

        while (fscanf(input, "%1023s %d %1023s %lf", name, &quantity, item, &price) == 4) {
            printf("%s %d %s %.2lf\n", name, quantity, item, price);
        }
        printf("EOF\n");
        fclose(input);
    } else {
        printf("Cannot open input file\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `&name` --> `name` and comment about no width limit  avec `"%s"`?

Comment: This code causes a crazy overflow and memory map thing.

Comment: If the input file has very long words, the code would indeed have caused potential buffer overflows. `fscanf()` is clunky and limited, it is difficult to recover from formatting errors, it should only be used for *quick and dirty throw away toy programs*.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this instead of just doing a hack job and removing the last line processed

Yes, there is.

Check the return value from `fscanf` in your code.  The call will fail when you try to read past the end of the file.

You should be checking it anyway.  There are even a lot of people who post here who will opine that you shouldn't use any of the `*scanf()` functions anyway because they're very difficult if not impossible to use in any robust way.  There's almost always a way you can feed one of the `*scanf()` functions data that will cause problems.